# India and Turkey currency symbols don't display in Winforms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, locale, currency-formatting

I'm adding currency symbols to a ListView and finding that all symbols display properly, with the exception of those for India and Turkey, which display a box character. In the debugger, these currency symbols display properly. I tried setting the ListView font to the same font as the debugger (Consolas) but that didn't work. I also tried a Label control instead of the ListView, and found the same issue, so it is presumably not working for all Winforms controls. What am I missing?

```
// Jordan
// Displays correctly
label1.Text = new RegionInfo( "ar-JO" ).CurrencySymbol;

// India: as-IN, bn-IN, en-IN, gu-IN, hi-IN, kn-IN, kok-IN,
//        ml-IN, mr-IN, or-IN, pa-IN, sa-IN, ta-IN, te-IN
// Displays a box symbol
label1.Text = new RegionInfo( "pa-IN" ).CurrencySymbol;

// Turkey
// Displays a box symbol
label1.Text = new RegionInfo( "tr-TR" ).CurrencySymbol;
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, does the machine you are targetting have the font installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some fonts (including popular MS Sans Serif, Tachoma) don't have U+2089 and/or U+20BA glyphs (that are Indian an Turkish currency symbols), while some other (e.g. Calibri) have. It seems, that you have to change label1.Font.Name

Comment: Thank you, I didn't look at the Visual Studio fonts closely enough: the debugger locals window uses Segoe UI, not Consolas. I changed my Label and ListView to use this and the India symbols displayed properly. The Turkey symbol still does not, but I put that down to font choice again.